# General information about CGI redirections

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi

When I run my redirect cgi script (Perl), I just do the following:

```
print "Location: /new/url\n\n";
```

This works, but by default, it says Status:200 OK.  If I specify the status like 302 or 301 in the header, then the browser redirects. Otherwise, it still loads the content of the new url without changing the URL in a browser.

I would just like to understand how a browser processes a Location: Header but has 200 status and what are pros and cons of doing this instead of using 302 or 301?

Either a feedback or a link to an article discussing this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I would just like to understand how a browser processes a Location: Header but has 200 status and what are pros and cons of doing this instead of using 302 or 301?

A `Location` header causes only a redirect when combined with some 3xx code. This behavior is clearly defined in the HTTP standard. From [RFC 7231 7.1.2 Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2):

> For 201 (Created) responses, the Location value refers to the primary
> resource created by the request.  **For 3xx (Redirection) responses,
> the Location value refers to the preferred target resource for
> automatically redirecting the request.**

In other words: it makes no sense at all to use a `Location` header together with a response code 200. The `Location` header will simply be ignored by the browser in this case.

Comment: I believe what Steffen Ullrich is trying to say is that browsers shouldn't heed a Location header in a 200 response, so one should use the appropriate 3xx response rather then relying on the browser to guess what was meant.

Comment: Actually, up until today, I thought it automatically added Status: 302. But the interesting thing I noticed is how the data was delivered.  Here's a screenshot. https://snag.gy/rYMzuL.jpg The one that I forgot to add a 302 status to actually loaded the redirected page but in a different manner.  Trying to understand how that happened basically.  It's as if the server loaded the content of the page or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: I think I may have looked at the issue incorrectly. It should be how Apache responds, not how the browser responds.  So it seems that when I made the script say "Location: /sample.html\n\n"; the server just loaded the page sample.html directly since it's in the same server thus having a 200 status. When I tried it with "Location: http://some-othersite.com\n\n"; the server added a 302 response header automatically.I have a bit of clarity now.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make your life easier by using the [`redirect()` subroutine from CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Generating-a-redirection-header).

```
$ perl -MCGI=redirect -E'say redirect("https://example.com")'
Status: 302 Found
Location: https://example.com
```